# Как вывести повторяющиеся слова из массива в отдельный массив?

Tags: javascript

Вот такая проблема:

> Есть массив, в который будут попадать строки. В этих строках несколько
>   слов будут повторятся. Эти повторяющиеся слова надо будет убрать в
>   другой массив по одному.

Например:

Из строки "Дом лошадь трактор дом собака", нам надо создать массив в котором будет лежать только слово "дом", потому, что оно повторяется.

Вот такой код я написал, но он мне все слова по одному сует в новый массив

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function CheckStr(str) {
 var newStr = [];
    var words = str.split(' ');
   
    for (var word of words) {
      if(words.indexOf(word, 0) !== -1) newStr += word + " ";
    }

    newStr = newStr.trim();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newStr;            
  }

  CheckStr("Дом лошадь трактор бульдозер дом кухня");
}
```

Comment: а разве Дом и дом из-за регистра это не разные слова?

Если я пройдусь фильтром сделав в массиве слов дом одним регистром. один из них повторяющийся удалится 
const arr = ["дом", "лошадь", "трактор", "бульдозер", "дом", "кухня"];  
    const result = arr.filter( (item, pos) => {
        return arr.indexOf(item) === pos;
    })
alert(result);

Comment: Вы правы) Я когда писал тут пример, просто автоматом написал первое слово с большой буквы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А проблема в том, что Вы строку разбили на слова, и в строке ищете эти же слова. Естественно они будут совпадать со строкой.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    function CheckStr(str) {
        var newStr = [];
        var words = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');

        var result = words.reduce(function(acc, el) { // Посчитали количество одинаковых слов
            acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;
            return acc;
        }, {});

        Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key, id){ // Если слова повторяются - выводим
            if(result[key] > 1) newStr += key + " ";
        });

        console.log(newStr);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newStr;

    }

    CheckStr("Дом лошадь лошадь трактор бульдозер дом кухня");
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
let str = "Дом дом лошадь трактор бульдозер дом кухня кухня";

let arr = str.split(" ");
let words = {};
// Каждое новое слово будет сохраняться в качестве ключа объекта.
// А вместо значения - количество подобных слов в строке.

for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  let word = arr[i].toLowerCase();
  
  words[word] = ( words[word] ) ? words[word] + 1 : 1; // см. `Тернарный оператор`
}

console.log( JSON.stringify( Object.entries(words) ) );

let repeating = Object.entries(words).filter(arr => arr[1] > 1).map(arr => arr[0]);

console.log( repeating.join(", ") );
```